# Mastermind game if statement problems

Tags: java, if-statement, bluej

I am trying to make it so when two or more of my if statements work they dont both print instead they just say two are in the correct spot or more it more works. Im not sure if im suppose to make more if statements of if i am suppose to use another statement or a forloop.

```
               //If Statements
                if (Gameboard[0] == Secret_code[0]) {
                    System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
    } 
                if (Gameboard[1] == Secret_code[1]) {
                    System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
    }
                if (Gameboard[2] == Secret_code[2]) {
                    System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
    }
                if (Gameboard[3] == Secret_code[3]) {
                    System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: At least, it seems that your code could be simplified to `if (Gameboard[i] == Secret_code[i]) { System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot"); }` for some `i`, e.g. within a [`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop.

Comment: I'd suggest first count the hits and afterwards to the output based on that count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution "In words"

Instead of just checking whether the code is correct in each spot and then printing immediately, consider creating a variable which will count the number of times the peg has been correct. Then don't print anything until you know that the value of this variable has taken into consideration all of the elements of `Secret_code` (a good way (the "right" way)) to do this would be to loop through the `Secret_Code` array and use your new variable to count each time the code is correct.

Finally, print the message to the user using the variable which holds the information about how many are correct.

I won't include example code so you can be sure to implement and understand it yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over `Gameboard[x] == Secret_code[x]` checks and print the total at the end.

EDIT: removed code in the spirit of promoting learning.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a compound condition

```
if(cond1 || cond2 ||.....){print};
```

The nature of Java is that once the first true condition is encountered, further evaluation stops and the print statement is executed. This is just one of many solutions. But if your array index is huge, I don't recommend my solution since a compound condition should only be about 3 or 4 at most, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Gameboard[0] == Secret_code[0]) {
                System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
} 
if (Gameboard[1] == Secret_code[1]) {
                System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
}
if (Gameboard[2] == Secret_code[2]) {
                System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
}
if (Gameboard[3] == Secret_code[3]) {
                System.out.println ("You have one in the correct spot");
}
```

should be changed to something akin to

```
private static final String[] numbers = {zero, one, two, three, four};

int correctCount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < /*4*/ GameBoard.length; i++) {
     if(Gameboard[i] == Secret_code[i]) {
         currentCount++;
     }
}
System.out.println("You have " + numbers[currentCount] + " in the correct spot.");
```